# Insertion Sort in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

Can you please help me to understand why this piece of code is not working. I am meant to write insertion sort and apply it to the file to sort its elements. However, it even fails to print the k-th elements in the while construct. I am using Windows and working in Git Bash.

```
j=0
for line in $(cat $1)
do
        elements[$j]="$line"
        j=$((j+1))
done


for i in $(seq "${#elements[@]}");
do
        key=${elements[i]}
        echo index: $i Key: $key
        k=$((i-1))
        while [ $k -gt 0 ] && [ ${elements[k]} > $key ]; do
                echo ${elements[k]} $key
                elements[$((k+1))]=${elements[k]}
                k=$((k-1))
        done
        elements[$((k+1))]=$key
done
```

The file I am reading as array elements is a .txt file with the following information:

```
3
1
2
3
2
```

Comment: @KamilCuk I did not know about readarray. It is an exercise to implement insertion sort. I made this changes and now it does not print anything.

Comment: The first loop starts with variable j uninitialized and thus array elements is not properly assigned.
On line 13 symbol ">" is treated by bash as output redirection not as comparison operator.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg  I forgot to type j but I had it originally. I will edit it

Comment: Don't use `for` and `cat` together like this; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a significant number of basic errors in your script. Before posting on StackOverflow, you will always want to use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix all basic errors.

While you generally do not use hand-written sorting routines in shell programming (utilities like `sort` are used), for a learning exercise there is nothing wrong with doing so. As mentioned in the comments, to fill an array from the lines of an input file, use `readarray` or use `mapfile` (both are equivalent). For example if providing the filename as the first argument to your script, you can fill `array` from the filename given (or read from `stdin` by default) using:

```
infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"           ## set filename or read from stdin
[ -r "$infile" ] || {               ## validate file readable
    printf "error: invalid filename.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

readarray -t array < "$infile"      ## readarray from file
```

By using `$(seq "${#elements[@]}")` you are creating an indexing nightmare. In bash valid array indexes are from `0 -> n-1`, however by using `$(seq "${#elements[@]}")` you are providing numbers `1 -> n` (which you will have to subtract `1` from to map to valid indexes. Instead you are better served by using a C-style `for` loop and staying with indexes from the array itself with, for example:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#elements[@]}; i++)); do
    ...
done
```

Next, as noted above in the comments your attempted comparison with `[ ${elements[k]} > $key ]` fails because within `[ ... ]` the `>` operates as a *redirection* instead of a comparison. If you are using the arithmetic operator `((....))` for the test, then `>` provides the *greater-than* comparison.

Finally, if you are going to the trouble of writing an insertion sort for an array in bash, you may as well make it a function so it is reusable. The only caveat there is bash doesn't provide a direct mechanism for passing an array to a function. (which is another reason you generally do not find hand-rolled sorting functions in bash)

You can however, for the purpose of this learning exercise, expand the array (e.g. `"${elements[@]}"` ) and then capture the elements in a `local` array within the function for sorting and then output the elements for reading back into the original array. For example, you could write an `inssort()` function taking advantage of that similar to:

```
## inssort() expects expanded array as positional parameters
#  outputs sorted array to stdout
inssort() {
    [ $# -gt 1 ] || {   ## validate at least 2 arguments given
        printf "error: cannot sort single value.\n" >&2
        return 1
    }
    local arr=( "$@" )  ## local array to insert values in sort order
    local n=${#arr[@]}  ## local values to use in sort
    local i=0
    local j=0
    local tmp=0

    ## insertion sort arr
    for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
        for ((j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)); do
            if (( ${arr[j]} > ${arr[$((j+1))]} )); then
                tmp=${arr[j]}
                arr[j]=${arr[$((j+1))]}
                arr[$((j+1))]=$tmp
            else
                break
            fi
        done
    done

    echo "${arr[@]}"    ## output sorted array
}
```

An then back in your script your could call and capture the results similar to:

```
array=( $(inssort "${array[@]}") )  ## insertion sort array
```

I can't impress on you enough, for sorting in an actual shell script, rely on the utilities that have been written to handle sorting, like `sort`. But for completion of this example, you could put your script together similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

## inssort() expects expanded array as positional parameters
#  outputs sorted array to stdout
inssort() {
    [ $# -gt 1 ] || {   ## validate at least 2 arguments given
        printf "error: cannot sort single value.\n" >&2
        return 1
    }
    local arr=( "$@" )  ## local array to insert values in sort order
    local n=${#arr[@]}  ## local values to use in sort
    local i=0
    local j=0
    local tmp=0

    ## insertion sort arr
    for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
        for ((j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)); do
            if (( ${arr[j]} > ${arr[$((j+1))]} )); then
                tmp=${arr[j]}
                arr[j]=${arr[$((j+1))]}
                arr[$((j+1))]=$tmp
            else
                break
            fi
        done
    done

    echo "${arr[@]}"    ## output sorted array
}

infile="${1:-/dev/stdin}"           ## set filename or read from stdin
[ -r "$infile" ] || {               ## validate file readable
    printf "error: invalid filename.\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

readarray -t array < "$infile"      ## readarray from file
echo "array  : ${array[*]}"         ## output original array

array=( $(inssort "${array[@]}") )  ## insertion sort array

echo "sorted : ${array[*]}"         ## output sorted array
```

Then you can either pass input to the script on `stdin` or provide a filename to read the array elements from, e.g.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/20int.txt
91
-72
5
-33
-60
-54
95
13
62
1
70
-3
68
-99
89
77
100
8
31
-43
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash inssortarr.sh dat/20int.txt
array  : 91 -72 5 -33 -60 -54 95 13 62 1 70 -3 68 -99 89 77 100 8 31 -43
sorted : -99 -72 -60 -54 -43 -33 -3 1 5 8 13 31 62 68 70 77 89 91 95 100
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions, then after you have finished your exercise, rely on the shell utility `sort` to handle your sorting needs. It will be much faster and much less error-prone...

Comment: One small nit: unless the file system as an entry for `/dev/stdin`, the `-r` won't work (I think). `bash` only handles `/dev/stdin` itself if it is part of a redirection.

Comment: Also, there's no reason you can't sort a single value; if `n == 1`, then your loop simply isn't entered and `arr` is output as-is.